# Nativescript -- Hide Android Status Bar in Alerts and Dialogs

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

Our N/Angular app is running in full screen mode. When an alert or a dialog is opened the previously hidden status bar reappears. Is there a way to hide the status bar on alerts/dialogs?

Here is the code we use to set to full screen mode:

```
const View = android.view.View;
const window = androidApp.startActivity.getWindow();
  const decorView = window.getDecorView();
  decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
      View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
      View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
  );
```

Comment: Can you share the sample code, what method you are using to hide it?

Comment: @Manoj - I've edited the post to show how we are setting to full screen.

Comment: Did you modify your Android Theme? Try hiding the titlebar from your theme.

Comment: Do you mean the actionbar? We are not using the native actionbar.

Comment: In your sample code, you do not hide ActionBar, it's still there. But I was talking about hiding title bar from Android theme which should be applied on Dialog too before shown.

Comment: We add actionbar.hidden = true

Honestly, I haven't figured out how to modify the theme. We just add styles to app.common.scss. If that modifies the theme, then yes.

Comment: I think at least to hide navigation bar you will have to do it programmatically, you may have to run the same code above every time when the dialog is closed.

Comment: Yes that's what I've been doing. I was hoping there was a different way to handle it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, in Native Script Angular wrapping the dialog component with a Page tag and adding `[actionBarHidden]="true"` resolves the problem if your dialog content is below you Navigation bar on android, and also adds a background on iOS.